# Im getting an IndexError: list assignment index out of range

Tags: python, pandas

I am getting an error and I'm not sure what is causing the error to occur.

The error is:

```
Parts[n] = PN
IndexError: list assignment index out of range
```

The code I'm using is this. I'm pretty new to python and tried to look out similar problems but didn't seem to find anything exactly similar to this. Any help would be appreciated.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_excel(r'C:\Users\md77879\Desktop\Test.xls')

Parts = list()
Prices = list()

print("\nEnter 'exit' to end")
PN = input('Enter PN: ')
Parts.append(PN)

Number = (df['Part Number'] == PN)
print(df[Number][['Part Number', 'Price']])

i, n = 0, 0

while PN != ('exit'):
    n = n + 1
    PN = input('   ')
    Number = df['Part Number'] == PN
    print(df[Number][['Part Number', 'Price']])
    Parts[n] = PN
    for i in range(0, n):
        print(Parts[i])
```

Comment: check `print( len(Parts), n )` - it seems length of list is smaller then `n`

Comment: to add new item at the end of list you should use `Parst.append(PN)`

Comment: instead of `for i in range(0, n): print(Parts[i])` you can do `for item in Parts: print(item)` - so you don't need `n`

Answer (score 0):

Check if (n >= len(Parts)), that should be the reason you're getting an IndexError.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that you're trying to modify the list Parts on an index which does not exists yet. 
Try to replace

```
Parts[n] = PN
```

with

```
Parts.append(PN)
```

That should solve your problem